# How to completely remove ubuntu (18.04 Gnome) dock on apps screen

Tags: 18.04, gnome, dock

I removed standard ubuntu dock, and i want to delete this dock, when using "win" key and i see all running apps (dock on left side):
[I highlighted that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0zOc.png)

Is it possible to remove it? (Because i do not using it, and that dock is just interferes :c)

P.S Sorry for bad english. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the [solution](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/805/hide-dash/), sorry for question! :)